# How to define an X column width using macro

Tags: tabularray

I want to create a table using tabularx with expandable columns and their width defined by macro like this

```
\def\temp{2}
\begin{tblr}{colspec = {X[\temp]X}, hlines, vlines}%
    1 & 2
\end{tblr}
```

but I get an error

```
Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
```

Comment: I changed the tag you are not using `tabularx` but `tabularray` package `tblr` environment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `X[co=\temp]`

```
\documentclass{article}
%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/709818/how-to-define-an-x-column-width-using-macro#709818
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}
\def\temp{2}
\begin{tblr}{
colspec = {X[co=\temp]X}, hlines, vlines}%
1 & 2
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]